# Can't reset mysql root password

Tags: mysql, linux, centos

I followed these instructions for resetting the mysql password: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/resetting-permissions.html

But somehow it doesn't work in my environment.

First, I created a sql file that reset root password like this.

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('foobar') WHERE User='root';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

And `sudo service mysqld stop` then `sudo mysqld_safe --init-file=/etc/mysql_grant.sql &`.

Then I tried to connect database by root `mysql -u root -pfoobar`, which failed with this error:

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (111)
```

Next I tried to use `mysqld`, but there are not, so I use `mysqld_safe` instead.

`sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &`, then `mysql -u root`.

I tried also `sudo service mysqld start --skip-grant-tables`, then `mysql -u root`.

But everything fails with same error message.

What can I do to reset root password anything else?

I'm using `CentOS release 6.5 (Final)` and `mysql --version` outputs:

`mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.1.73, for redhat-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.1`

*Edit*

This is my `/etc/my.cnf`.

```
[client]
port                           = 3306
socket                         = /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock

[mysqld_safe]
socket                         = /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock

[mysqld]
user                           = mysql
pid-file                       = /var/run/mysql/mysql.pid
socket                         = /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
port                           = 3306
datadir                        = /var/lib/mysql

[mysql]
!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d
```

And I do have `/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock`.

*Edit 2*

`sudo mysqld_safe --init-file=/etc/mysql_grant.sql -S /var/lib/mysqld.sock &` gave me this message. Somehow it ends just after stating. `sudo mysqld_safe --init-file=/etc/mysql_grant.sql -S /var/lib/mysql.sock &` gave me same error.

```
[1] 4700
140411 17:59:52 mysqld_safe Logging to '/var/lib/mysql/[MYSERVERNAME].err'.
140411 17:59:52 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
140411 17:59:52 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysql/mysql.pid ended
```

Answer (score 1):

Its not the password reset problem..

Its socket file problem. Kindly set the socket file path in your init file or eplicilty mention it while stating the server.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your advise. But I couldn't find out what exactly I should do to "set the socket file path". I added `my.cnf` to my question. I think this configuration tells server about socket file. Can you tell me more specific what should I do?

Comment: Use the socket file path when you start the server in this command:- sudo mysqld_safe --init-file=/etc/mysql_grant.sql -S /var/lib/mysqld.sock &

Comment: I tried `mysqld.sock` and `mysql.sock`, but both didn't work for me.

Comment: Whats the error in this file?
"/var/lib/mysql/[MYSERVERNAME].err"

Comment: I had a `[ERROR] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Can't create/write to file '/var/run/mysql/mysql.pid' (Errcode: 2)` error in that file, and there is only `/var/run/mysqld/` directory. I fix the `pid-file`, then it works. I have no idea why the process was running at first place, though.

Comment: this error is due to either you dont have the directory /var/run/mysql or the directory doesnt have permissions